# How to configure stroke width?

Tags: android, android-studio, stroke

For example I want to make my button with stroke in the:

- top 2dp
- bottom 1dp
- left 3dp
- right 2dp

What should I write in xml file?

Example :

```xml
<stroke
android:width="1dp"
android:color="#919187"
/>
```

Comment: Could you update the question with more information. For example, what programming language are you using and what are you trying to style?

Comment: Android studio, Java.